# Replace one occurrence with regexp

Tags: regex, go

I want to replace a only one instance with a regex rather than all of them. How would I do this with Go's `regexp` library?

input: `foobar1xfoobar2x`
regex: `bar(.)x`
replacement: `baz$1`

`ReplaceAllString` output: `foobaz1foobaz2`
`ReplaceOneString` output: `foobaz1foobar2x`

Comment: That depends on the API. What are you using now? This may help us read the docs for you.

Comment: @Qtax, I'm using Go's regexp library [`Regexp.ReplaceAllString`](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.ReplaceAllString). An equivalent api for `ReplaceOneString` doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: You could try the [following](http://regex101.com/r/mX7tN4) as a workaround (didn't test it thoroughly)

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV, that solves this one case, but I'm looking for a general solution.

Comment: Actually that solution is very generic. It will always replace the first match with your replacement and leave everything after untouched.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, if you use lazy match and use anchors for beginning and end, you can have the replace first behavior:

```
replace `^(.*?)bar(.*)$` with `$1baz$2`.
```

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    src := "foobar1xfoobar2x"
    pat := regexp.MustCompile("^(.*?)bar(.*)$")
        repl := "${1}baz$2"
    output := pat.ReplaceAllString(src, repl)
    fmt.Println(output)
}
```

**Output**

```
foobaz1xfoobar2x
```

Comment: you need to curly the group variables if they make valid identifier names with the following characters, see the updated answer

Comment: Wouldn't appending a `(.*)` to the end of the regex along with a suitable substitution var be enough?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. The most clean solution I've come up with:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    re, _ := regexp.Compile("[a-z]{3}")
    s := "aaa bbb ccc"

    // Replace all strings
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString(s, "000"))

    // Replace one string
    found := re.FindString(s)
    if found != "" {
        fmt.Println(strings.Replace(s, found, "000", 1))
    }
}
```

Running:

```
$ go run test.go 
000 000 000
000 bbb ccc
```

Comment: This does not work correctly when the regexp is complex enough, e.g. matching on word boundaries will cause this to incorrectly replace an earlier part of the string: https://go.dev/play/p/gWejkYZ8dB6

Answer (score 3):

I cound't use accepted solution because my pattern was very complicated. 
I ended up with using ReplaceAllStringFunc :
https://play.golang.org/p/ihtuIU-WEYG

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

var pat = regexp.MustCompile("bar(.)(x)")

func main() {
    src := "foobar1xfoobar2x"
    flag := false
    output := pat.ReplaceAllStringFunc(src, func(a string) string {
        if flag {
            return a
        }
        flag = true
        return pat.ReplaceAllString(a, "baz$1$2")
    })
    fmt.Println(output)
}
```